# To get words center in existing line

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to center the input TextField below on the line. I have already used mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, but it is not working. I also tried to insert my code within center tags, but that didn't work either. How can I resolve this?

```
 Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Text(documentSnapshot["name"],style:TextStyle(fontSize:20)),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Text(documentSnapshot["description"],style:TextStyle(fontSize:20)),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Text(documentSnapshot["tableNumber"].toString(),style:TextStyle(fontSize:20)),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: Did you try to use `textAlign: TextAlign.center` property on the `Text` widget ? It could help to post a picture of what you have / what you want to achieve as your description is a bit hard to understand

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `textAlign: TextAlign.center` in Text widget. It will help you to get text in center of the Expanded Widget.